# Bootstrap Fixed Column and Other Columns

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is the code I am currently using:

```html
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <a href="#">1</a>
            <a href="#">2</a>
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <a href="#">4</a>
            <a href="#">5</a>
            <a href="#">6</a>
            <a href="#">7</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-9">
           
           <div class="col-md-3">This is product 1 </div>
           <div class="col-md-3"> This is product  2 </div>
           <div class="col-md-3"> This is product  3</div>
           
           
           <div class="col-md-3">This is product 1 </div>
           <div class="col-md-3"> This is product 2 </div>
           <div class="col-md-3"> This is product 3</div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it currently appears.
[image]

Though this is how I would like it to appear.
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add .row class and it will be inline
2. or you can add style="display: inline-block" to all the div's with products.
3. also you can add to parent style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap" and child style="flex: 1 1 33%"

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
      **<div class="row">**
       <div class="col-md-3">This is product 1 </div>
       <div class="col-md-3"> This is product  2 </div>
       <div class="col-md-3"> This is product  3</div>
      **</div>**
      **<div class="row">**
       <div class="col-md-3">This is product 1 </div>
       <div class="col-md-3"> This is product 2 </div>
       <div class="col-md-3"> This is product 3</div>
      **</div>**
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `row` class to your element with `col-md-9`.

Also, bootstrap has a max of 12 columns so you want to have each child element take up 4 columns instead of 3.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="col-md-9 row">
           
           <div class="col-sm-4">This is product 1 </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4"> This is product  2 </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4"> This is product  3</div>
           
           
           <div class="col-sm-4">This is product 1 </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4"> This is product 2 </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4"> This is product 3</div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```